# App pool recycle

Tags: iis-7, w3wp, worker-process

We are working on an application that serves request 24 * 7 and none of the request should be missed. This application is hosted on IIS in load balanced environment. Primary server group P1 and C1, while the back up servers to primary servers are P2 and C2. So, requests are sent in load balanced manner to P1 and C1. If both P1 and C1 go down, the P2 and C2 are up. 
We are trying to work on a strategy so none of our requests are missed. Plan is to bring primary servers P1 and C1 down so requests are forwarded to back up. Then bring the primary servers up and work on back up servers. 
My question around it is how to ensure that worker process serves the last request it receives before we bring the application down for primary servers. As mentioned earlier, the intention is to ensure none of the requests are missed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that *none* of the requests are missed, you may be waiting a good long while--any requests in progress at the time the recycle occurs are serviced by the original AppPool. Depending on your site, some of those requests could be large files with very slow connections, which could take literally *hours* to finish. At some point you may just want to whack the connections and move on, knowing that the caller will refresh their page, reconnect, or whatever to get back to where they were.

In any case, you don't need multiple servers for this.  IIS automatically (by default at least), drains requests from the old application instance while starting up the new one and sending new requests to that (during application updates). (Note however, that any requests to the new pool will likely stall for several seconds because the application is loading and initializing everything for the first time--this is normal and very difficult to avoid).

If you really do have multiple servers and want to switch request handling from one server to the other, you must have some kind of load balancing system in place, either a software load balancer such as Microsoft Network Load Balancing, or a hardware load balancer such as F5 Big-IP. In both of these situations, you have to somehow tell the load balancer to drain connections on the old application (or server) and route them to the new server. This may be done manually through their GUIs, or for an automated deployment system, will require integration with those systems.

Comment: We have load balanced server in place. It is a WCF service that we have hosted in IIS and it serves every request in milliseconds. So there is no issue like time consuming requests. The prime issue for us is that since response time is fast, we receive requests continually and need to ensure that the deployment doesn't impact the response.

Comment: I was checking this link to have some clarity - http://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/. This speaks of IISRESET. For app pool, is it possible that if I try to shut the app pool down (and not recycle it), would IIS ensure that worker process finishes all the requests before pool is shut down completely and not to send it any further requests as soon as App pool shut down request is received.

Comment: If you have an external load balancer, nothing IIS does matters. Just tell the load balancer to route new incoming requests to the second server--it should have some kind of indicator for when existing requests have completed for the first server, at which point you can safely do the update. Next, you'll probably want to do something to 'warm' the updated application (there are some newer IIS features related to this, but not on IIS 7 and I haven't looked into the details). Next, tell the load balancer to put the first server back in and run through the same process with the second server.

Comment: This is what we have been thinking of doing, the only apprehension here is that we do not want to miss any request.